# Add function to dynamically created images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a simple search function with AngularJS that allows you to type in an animal's name from the Chinese zodiac, and get images of compatible animals. I would like to extend this app so that clicking on one of the dynamically created elements would bring up the relevant list of animals.

My first thought was creating an click event listener on all image elements, but this didn't work with angular. I would really appreciate any direction or help.

HTML

```
<div>
What Animal Are You?<input type="text" ng-model="animal"><input type="submit" ng-click="submit(animal)">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submit = function(submitAnimal){
$scope.disappear=false
$('.your-zodiac').empty()
$('.mortalEnemy').empty()
$('.friendsForever').empty()

$http.get('zodiac.json')
    .then(function(response) {
                var animalsData = response.data.animals
        function loopAnimals(arrayOfAnimals,element){
            for (var index in arrayOfAnimals){
                var animal = arrayOfAnimals[index]
                for (var loopAnimal in animalsData){
                    if(animalsData[loopAnimal].animal==animal){
                        var picture = animalsData[loopAnimal].picture
                        $(element).prepend("<img src='"+ picture +"' alt='"+animal+"'/>")
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (var loopAnimal in animalsData){
            if (animalsData[loopAnimal].animal==submitAnimal){ //compatibility test
                var picture = animalsData[loopAnimal].picture
                $('.your-zodiac').prepend("<img src='"+ picture +"' alt='"+submitAnimal+"'/>")
                var enemies = animalsData[loopAnimal].hate //hate array
                var friends = animalsData[loopAnimal].love
                loopAnimals(enemies,'.mortalEnemy')
                loopAnimals(friends,'.friendsForever')
                break;
            }
        }

    });
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9GtvFt5Kbvn1Sb98AXrA?p=preview

Comment: First, maybe write your code inside script.js for clarity, second loose all that jQuery stuff.

Comment: thank you, took your advice and code is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jQuery's on event listener for the dynamic images:

```
$('#zodiac').on("click",'img',function(){
    var animal = $(this).attr('alt')
    $scope.submit(animal)
})
```